# jmeter plugin maven test-jar

Tags: maven, testing, junit, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

Hi I'm trying to automate my JMeter load balancing test with the jmeter-maven-plugin from lazerycode. My JMeter tests uses premade junit class files which I pack into a test-jar with the maven-jar-plugin. But before the jar file is installed on my local maven repository maven starts the jmeter test. Is there a way I can install the test-jar so I can use it as a dependency in the jmeter plugin? below you'll find my jmeter plugin configuration.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jmeter-test</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jmeter</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>groupID</groupId>
                    <artifactId>artifactID</artifactId>
                    <version>${project-version}</version>
                    <type>test-jar</type>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <propertiesUser>
                    <current.protocol>http</current.protocol>
                    <current.dns>localhost</current.dns>
                    <current.port>8088</current.port>
                </propertiesUser>
                <testFilesDirectory>${basedir}/src/jmeter/tests/</testFilesDirectory>
                <ignoreResultErrors>true</ignoreResultErrors>
                <ignoreResultFailures>true</ignoreResultFailures>
                <useOldTestEndDetection>true</useOldTestEndDetection>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the test jar into a different module, then make the project with the jmeter plugin dependent on that module. You will then be able to install the tests then execute them in jmeter in a single Maven invocation.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by using an activation profile :-

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
                <id>ptest</id>
                <activation>
                    <property>
                        <name>ptest</name>
                    </property>
                </activation>

                <build>

                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/jmeter</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>

                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>1.4.1</version>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                                    <phase>verify</phase>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>jmeter</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                            <configuration>
                                <useOldTestEndDetection>true</useOldTestEndDetection>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </build>
            </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Using this approach you can install once, not using the profile, and then run subsequently with the profile turned on.